# Поддержка разных экранов IOS

Tags: ios, экран

Я новичок в разработке под ios. Столкнулся с проблемой поддержки разных экранов. Применив то, что понял насчет autoresizing и sizeclasses к успеху не пришел. В storyboard выставляю view по правому краю, на iphone 6 оно остаётся прилипшим к нему, на iphone 4 уходит за край экрана. Отключив sizeclasses стал упражняться с autoresize в коде и в storyboard. прописывал autoresizemask для leftmargin, добавлял к нему rightmargin, указывал численно в storyboard - результат один. Вопросы такие - правильным ли путем я пошёл, и как правильно использовать autoresize (применительно к контейнеру или view, указывать маску или численное значение, можно ли проигнорировать какие либо из marigns, например использовать левый отступ, но не обращать внимания на правый)

Ответ нужен теоретический, поэтому не привожу код. Надеюсь мне удалось изложить суть.

Comment: автолэйоут (используется для расположения элементов при вращении устройства) http://www.raywenderlich.com/115440/auto-layout-tutorial-in-ios-9-part-1-getting-started-2

Comment: adaptive layout (он же constraints) используются для расположения элементов на экранах разных размеров http://www.raywenderlich.com/113768/adaptive-layout-tutorial-in-ios-9-getting-started

Comment: только сейчас заметил в первом комментарии опечатка - autoresizing а не autolayout